# Deleting projects on pycharm

Tags: file, pycharm

I accidentally put my Documents folder in the projects section on the vertical side on pycharm and now I can't figure out how to delete it. Any help?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the folder, then press delete.
Don't worry, it just detach the folder instead of delete.

Comment: I can't delete it. I posted pictures to see if it was more helpful to visualize. It's not giving me a delete option.

Comment: You can add another folder to this project, then the delete option on Document will show.

Comment: You can't delete it because it's the only one folder in this project.

Comment: Is the problem solved? Please accept my answer... : )